# Trying to create a loop to copy cells from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, loops, copy

I am trying to build code to do the following:
In a workbook I have two sheets.
Sheet 2 has several columns, I want to create a loop to read each row in a particular column, lets say column D.  When the row in that column is not equal to zero, I want to copy the value in that row to a column in Sheet2, Lets say its Column G in sheet 2 but it would be the same row from column  D in sheet 1.

```
Example
Sheet 2                 Sheet 1
Column D             Column G
0             Don’t copy from Sheet 2
500               500 (Copied from Sheet 2)
20                20 (Copied from Sheet 2)
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out using an example from another post as well as looking at Felipe's suggestion.

I was using a function to find the last row in one of my sheets within a workbook as I was coping data.  By using this lastrow function I created a loop and was able to use an IF statement that allowed me to copy the row that had data to a column(s) in my other sheet

FirstRow = Range("A2").Value

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim b As Integer, Buy As Integer

```
    For b = 2 To LastRow
      If Range("F" & b).Value <> 0 Then
         Range("F" & b).Select
         Selection.Copy
         Sheets("T-1 BSR").Select
         Range("I" & b).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Range("J" & b).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Sheets("BAML Futures PnL").Select
      End If
    Next b
```

I also used the same logic as I had to use another column and multiply it by -1 when there was a sell

Dim s As Integer, Sell As Integer

```
    For s = 2 To LastRow
      If Range("G" & s).Value <> 0 Then
         Sell = Range("G" & s) * -1
         Range("G" & s).Value = Sell
         Range("G" & s).Select
         Selection.Copy
         Sheets("T-1 BSR").Select
         Range("I" & s).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Range("J" & s).Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Sheets("BAML Futures PnL").Select
      End If
    Next s
```

Not sure if this was the most efficient way but it does work

Answer (score -1):

I would go to create dynamic ranges & declare them in my VBA code.

So, after creating a dynamic range (using the Name Manager to define dynamic ranges using OFFSET), which is explained in here: [Create Dynamic Range (Offset)](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2017/07/19/excel-dynamic-named-range/), ...

... I would declare them at the beginning of my code. To declare a range using a the Name Manager, look here [Excel Named Ranges](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/named-ranges/vba-code.htm#:%7E:text=Named%20ranges%20can%20be%20very,the%20cells%20are%20still%20valid.).

... then name the column within the range, in order to assign a value to it. The following link leads to the Column property in [Range.Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columns).

... then, create your loop using Range_1 in Range_2 (Column): [Loop through Defined Range](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html).

... Finally, just compare the values using an If ([If Statement](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/if-then-statement.html)), retrieving the position of the cell when it's successful ([Range.Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.column) & [Range.Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.row)) & copying it to the second sheet ([Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)).

Comment: I was able to figure this out, using an example from another post as well as looking at Felipe's suggestion.  In my VBA code I was using a